# Should an ASP.NET REST service be used to back a MVC application and an Android application?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, soa

I am developing a web application and a mobile application. I need a way to access the information and perform the same operations from both the web client and the mobile client.

1. Users must have one of two types of accounts.
2. Users need to be able to access data belonging to their account after they authenticate.

Most of the literature that I see uses get requests to access information that isn't necessarily private(things such as weather data). Would I use a custom REST API to access and modify information belonging to users who must be authenticated or is there some other solution?

Answer (score 0):

REST is an architectural style. It is not a protocol. Whether the API is REST-compliant or not does not have anything to do with security.

For example, you can build a well-secured REST-compliant API on top of [HTTPS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTPS) and then you can use GET, POST etc. for private information.